# Why jhipster:import-jdl is giving me an IllegalAssociationException?

Tags: uml, jhipster

I have this UML:

```
entity Profile {
    creationDate Instant required
    bio String maxlength(7500)
}
entity Grupo {
    creationDate Instant required
    groupname String minlength(2) maxlength(100) required
    image ImageBlob
    isActive Boolean
}

// RELATIONSHIPS:
relationship OneToOne {
    Profile{grupo} to Grupo{profile}
}

relationship OneToMany {
    User{grupo} to Grupo{user(id) required}
}
// DTO for all
dto * with mapstruct

// Set pagination options
paginate all with pagination

// Set service options to all except few
service all with serviceImpl
```

and when I run it with yo jhipster:import-jdl it gives the following error:

```
IllegalAssociationException: Relationships from User entity is not supported in the declaration between User and Grupo.
Error jhipster:import-jdl ./src/main/scripts/raro.jh
```

**Is it NOT allowed to have a OneToMany relationship with the User Entity? The thing is that OneToOne relationships works fine.**

Because when I change the relationship to ManyToOne, it works

```
entity Profile {
    creationDate Instant required
    bio String maxlength(7500)
}

entity Groups {
    creationDate Instant required
    groupname String minlength(2) maxlength(100) required
    image ImageBlob
    isActive Boolean
}


// RELATIONSHIPS:
relationship OneToOne {
    Profile{groups(groupname)} to Groups{profile}
}

// relationship OneToMany {
//    User{groups} to Groups{user(id) required} 
// }

relationship ManyToOne {
    Groups{user(id) required} to User{groups} 
}


// DTO for all
dto * with mapstruct

// Set pagination options
paginate all with pagination

// Set service options to all except few
service all with serviceImpl
```

**Why? Am I doing something worng in the first example?
Thanks**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JHipster does not allow `OneToMany` relationships to the user by default.  If you need this, you will have to manually change the code.

> Please note that the User entity, which is handled by JHipster, is specific. You can do:
>
> - many-to-one relationships to this entity (a Car can have a many-to-one relationship to a User)
> - many-to-many and one-to-one relationships to the User entity, but the other entity must be the owner of the relationship (a Team can have a many-to-many relationship to User, but only the team can add/remove users, and a user cannot add/remove a team)

https://www.jhipster.tech/managing-relationships/